# XSLT test any childs value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to test an xml message if it contains any object with modtime bigger then a certain value. Currently I use one stylesheet explicitly listing every path in the xml to be tested.

```
<xsl:if test="(translate(proot_modtime,'-T:Z','')>=translate('2017-09-30T00:00:45','-T:Z','')) 
      or (translate(a/a/pa_modtime,'-T:Z','')>=translate('2017-09-30T00:00:45','-T:Z','')) 
      or  (translate(b/b/pb_modtime,'-T:Z','')>=translate('2017-09-30T00:00:45','-T:Z','')) 
      ">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
```

I tend to forget to update the stylesheet, when the xml message changes. That is why i am seaching for a more generic option. That looks for all child nodes, that contain the word *modtime* and should check all of them. I tried to use XPath Expression, matching all Modtime-Nodes

```
<xsl:if test="(translate(//*[ends-with(name(), '_modtime')],'-T:Z','')>=translate('2017-09-30T00:00:45','-T:Z',''))">       <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
```

Unfortunately the above code snippet, will only test the very first *_modtime node and ignores all other. Actually i want to test all

Does somebody have any idea, to describe the following in XSL:
"if any modtime node in the XML tree contains a value bigger then x, copy the whole xml"

Example XML:

```
<root>
  <proot_modtime>2017-09-28T00:00:00</proot_modtime>
  <a>
    <a>
      <pa_modtime>2017-10-01T16:15:15</pa_modtime>
    </a>
  </a>
  <b>
    <b>
      <pb_modtime>2017-09-30T00:00:00</pb_modtime>
    </b>
  </b>
</root>
```

Complete XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:if test="(translate(//*[ends-with(name(), '_modtime')],'-T:Z','')>=translate('2017-09-30T00:00:45','-T:Z',''))">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *copy the whole xml*? Whole XML document or just the node tag? What happens if criteria is not met?

Comment: the xsl shall either copy the whole message or transform it to an empty string. Because messages with modtime < x are not relevant for me. Either output = input or output = empty. Depending on the condition

Comment: Again, what does *message* mean? The entire XML document? All of `<root>`?

Comment: If you're constrained to use XSLT 1.0, please say so. Manipulating dates and times is much easier in current versions of the language.

Comment: @Parfait, yes the entire xml document

Comment: @MichaelKay still using very old transformer due to oher requirements. But anyway i would be interested in the alternative syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want

```
<xsl:if test="//*[ends-with(name(), '_modtime')][translate(.,'-T:Z','')>=translate('2017-09-30T00:00:45','-T:Z','')]">
```